# Array assignment produces NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, arrays, nullpointerexception

I am experiencing problems when assigning a value to an array, which is previously declared like so:

```
Enemy[] enemies = new Enemy[100];
```

I also have another variable defining the number of enemies spawned:

```
int numEnemies = 0;
```

Later, I (attempt to) dynamically assign members of this array to `Enemy` objects when the screen is touched:

```
public void spawnEnemy() {
Enemy enemy = new Enemy(...);
... initialise enemy ...
enemies[numEnemies++] = enemy;  // this line causes NPE
}
```

I have this stack trace:

```
01-24 02:00:28.509: E/AndroidRuntime(1394): FATAL EXCEPTION: UpdateThread
01-24 02:00:28.509: E/AndroidRuntime(1394): Process: com.example.menutest, PID: 1394
01-24 02:00:28.509: E/AndroidRuntime(1394): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-24 02:00:28.509: E/AndroidRuntime(1394): at com.example.menutest.GameScene.spawnEnemy(GameScene.java:333)
01-24 02:00:28.509: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at com.example.menutest.GameScene.initJoints(GameScene.java:325)
01-24 02:00:28.509: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at com.example.menutest.GameScene.loadLevel(GameScene.java:189)
01-24 02:00:28.509: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at com.example.menutest.GameScene.createScene(GameScene.java:80)
01-24 02:00:28.509: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at com.example.menutest.BaseScene.<init>(BaseScene.java:24)
01-24 02:00:28.509: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at com.example.menutest.GameScene.<init>(GameScene.java:32)
01-24 02:00:28.509: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at com.example.menutest.SceneManager$1.onTimePassed(SceneManager.java:118)
01-24 02:00:28.509: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at org.andengine.engine.handler.timer.TimerHandler.onUpdate(TimerHandler.java:94)
01-24 02:00:28.509: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at org.andengine.engine.handler.UpdateHandlerList.onUpdate(UpdateHandlerList.java:47)
01-24 02:00:28.509: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onUpdateUpdateHandlers(Engine.java:618)
01-24 02:00:28.509: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onUpdate(Engine.java:605)
01-24 02:00:28.509: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onTickUpdate(Engine.java:568)
01-24 02:00:28.509: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at org.andengine.engine.Engine$UpdateThread.run(Engine.java:858)
```

EDIT:

My app is written in AndEngine, so the CreateScene() method is called from a SceneManager which I am certain works perfectly.

```
public class GameScene extends BaseScene {

Enemy enemies[] = new Enemy[100];
int numEnemies = 0;

    public void createScene() {
        ResourcesManager.getInstance().setGameScene(this);
        this.setOnSceneTouchListener((IOnSceneTouchListener) ResourcesManager.mBaseGameActivity);
        createBackground();
        createHUD();
        createPhysicsWorld();
                // the above set up scene for later use
        loadLevel(1);
    }



    public void loadLevel(int levelID) {
        initJoints();
    }



    private void initJoints() {
        mPlanet = new Planet(400, 225, ResourcesManager.getInstance().planet, mVertexBufferObjectManager, 500);
        mPlanet.mBody = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(mPhysicsWorld, mPlanet, BodyType.StaticBody, FIXTURE_DEF);
        mPlanet.mBody.setUserData(mPlanet);
        this.attachChild(mPlanet);
        mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(mPlanet, mPlanet.mBody, true, true));

        float x1 = 200;
        float y1 = 112;
        mSatellite = SatelliteFactory.createSatellite(SatelliteType.BASIC, x1, y1, mVertexBufferObjectManager, mPlanet);
        this.attachChild(mSatellite);

    spawnEnemy(); // causes exception

    }



    private void spawnEnemy() {
        float y = getRandomY();
        float maxHealth = 100;
        Enemy enemy = new Enemy(0, y, ResourcesManager.getInstance().satellite_no_image, ResourcesManager.mVertexBufferObjectManager, maxHealth);
        enemy.mBody = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(mPhysicsWorld, enemy, BodyType.DynamicBody, FIXTURE_DEF);

        this.attachChild(enemy);
        enemy.mBody.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2((mPlanet.getX() - enemy.mBody.getPosition().x) / PhysicsConstants.PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT,
                (mPlanet.getY() - enemy.mBody.getPosition().y) / PhysicsConstants.PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT));
        enemy.mBody.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(mPlanet.getX(), mPlanet.getY() - y));
        mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(enemy, enemy.mBody, true, true));

        enemies[numEnemies++] = enemy; // NPE
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. I'm certain that the problem lies in code you haven't shown - for example, if your initialization is accidentally of a *local* variable in a constructor, leaving an *instance* variable uninitialized.

Comment: After edit I can see the array `enemies` but where is it initialized? Please make sure that you have initialized an array.

Comment: Look for `enemies = null` in your code.

Comment: where is `numEnemies` initialized?

Comment: You might want to show a complete section of code instead of multiple, separate parts. As it is now it is hard to tell which pieces are from where and so on. Your variable scope could be a huge factor in this.

Comment: I also don't see the initialization of the enemies array

Comment: This isn't a complete program, and it's far from short. In particular, it doesn't show *where* you're declaring and initializing the variable.

Comment: @likeasomebody Well - something on that line is probably null. You might just want to check what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll explain what happens:

**How do I call an instance method before calling the instance constructor?**

```
class B {
  B() {
    m();
  }
  void m() {
    System.out.println("B.m()");
  }
}
class X extends B {
  int x = 8;
  void m() {
    System.out.println("X.m() x="+x);
  }
}

public class A {
    public static void main(String[] p) {
        X x = new X();
        x.m();
    }
}
```

Let's run it:

```
$ javac A.java 

$ java A
X.m() x=0
X.m() x=8
```

This kind of misbehavior is not possible in C++ where *B.m()* rather than *X.m()* would be called from within the base class constructor.

The constructor *B()* is called automatically before executing any code from the constructor *X()*, and so the method *X.m()* is called before any code within the constructor *X()* receives control.

Answer (score 1):

Please add a Log.d() and see what is shown:

```
Log.d("~~~","\n\n\n\n~~~ enemies="+enemies+"  enemy="+enemy);
enemies[numEnemies++] = enemy;  // this line causes NPE
```

I suspect this is because of the order of initialization, the function definitely is invoked from a constructor or initializer.

Note also the following in the log:

```
at com.example.menutest.GameScene.initJoints(GameScene.java:325)
at com.example.menutest.GameScene.loadLevel(GameScene.java:189)
at com.example.menutest.GameScene.createScene(GameScene.java:80)
at com.example.menutest.BaseScene.<init>(BaseScene.java:24)
at com.example.menutest.GameScene.<init>(GameScene.java:32)
```

the GameScene constructor calls the BaseScene constructor which in turn calls GameScene methods -- before the GameScene instance creation is finished.

In addition, you write: *I (attempt to) dynamically assign members of this array to Enemy objects when the screen is touched* but I see that the code is launched upon a timeout:

```
at com.example.menutest.SceneManager$1.onTimePassed(SceneManager.java:118)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, try this: just before the line where you get the NPE, add

```
if (enemy == null) System.out.println("enemy is null");
if (numEntries == null) System.out.println("numEntries is null");
if (enemies == null) System.out.println("enemies is null");
enemies[numEnemies++] = enemy; // NPE
```

Does that give you any useful information?

Comment: Probably... :( I'm a bit tempted to ask you why you would want a native array rather than using the Array class.

Comment: if I tried doing `enemies = new Enemy[100];` inside the spawnEnemy() method directly before the NPE, would it override the existing members?

Comment: It would. Please consider using the ArrayList, see if that works better.